# How do I remove a duplicate from a SELECT DISTINCT over multiple columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.month, 
                a.date 
           FROM a 
       ORDER BY a.bar DESC NULLS LAST;
```

month is a char, date is a date. I need to use the date column because that's the thing i'm ordering the results by. I'm getting this result:

```
foo | bar

 x---|---20-nov-15 00:00:00  
 y---|---31-oct-15 00:00:00  
 y---|---30-oct-15 00:00:00  
 z---|---28-sept-15 00:00:00
```

I am in need of a `WHERE` statement that would eliminate that duplicate Y from the result, I've been looking everywhere and couldn't find a solution

Comment: Do you actually have separate month, date, foo and bar columns - or have you just named them inconsistently in your example? (Your ordering also doesn't match the dates you've used; are they all supposed to be in the same year?)

Comment: Was a type-o, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would seem to want `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.month, MAX(a.date)
FROM a 
GROUP BY a.month;
```

Comment: If I add a `GROUP BY` I get _ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression_

Comment: @OctavianCatusanu try it now

Comment: That works, thank you. But is there any way I can modify that as a `WHERE` clause? I need to insert it as a restriction

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it: (You don't need to use `SELECT DISTINCT...`

```
SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FOO
                                ORDER BY BAR DESC) AS RN
            FROM @RESULT) x
        WHERE RN = 1
```

You use the row number and partition to separate your data by `Foo` and then order by descending `Bar`. (You can add more partitions as and when needed)

Then take Row number 1 to take the Maximum date for each `Foo`

Full working:

```
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE
   ([Foo] CHAR(1)  ,[Bar] DATETIME)

INSERT   INTO @RESULT
         SELECT   'x', '2015-11-20T00:00:00'
INSERT   INTO @RESULT
         SELECT   'y', '2015-10-31T00:00:00'
INSERT   INTO @RESULT
         SELECT   'y', '2015-10-30T00:00:00'
INSERT   INTO @RESULT
         SELECT   'z', '2015-09-28T00:00:00'


SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FOO
                                ORDER BY BAR DESC) AS RN
            FROM @RESULT) x
        WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use group by to solve this issue

```
SELECT a.month, a.date 
FROM a 
GROUP BY a.month 
ORDER BY a.bar DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: As I mentioned, the first answer works, but is there any way I can modify and use it as a `WHERE` clause? I need to insert it as a restriction

Comment: You aren't doing any aggregation of the columns that aren't in the group-by clause, so it'll get `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` - both from the select list, and from the order-by clause.